# After concatenating html elements the result variable return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my code it return 0 when i call result variable i want to add elements in html without DOM, means i want to re-create this whole html in JS using this code.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "old");
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "new");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.setAttribute("id", "paragraph")
    var domDiv = document.getElementById("old");
    var domNewDiv = document.getElementById("new");
    var domP = document.getElementById("paragraph");

    var result = domDiv + domNewDiv + domP;
    result;
```

[Code in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJIxW.png)

Comment: `domDiv + domNewDiv + domP` is invalid. You need to create a `div` tag and append all three `div` to that.

Comment: you can't concatenate objects. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById returns a Javascript Object. You cannot simply concatenate objects. But you can concatenate the html content of those objects for example:

```
var result = domDiv.innerHTML + domNewDiv.innerHTML + domP.innerHTML;
```